# Finding average memory access time, AMAT and global miss rate

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I'm quite confused about this question. So, I have IL1, DL1 and UL2 and when I try to find AMAT do I use the formula `AMAT = Hit Time(1) + Miss Rate * (Hit time(2) + Miss Rate * Miss Penalty` ? or Do I also add `Hit time(3)` because there are 3 miss rates

```
For Example: 0.4 + 0.1 * (0.8 + 0.05 * (10 + 0.02 * 48))
I used AMAT = Hit Time(1) + Miss Rate * (Hit time(2) + Miss Rate * (Hit time(3) + Miss Rate * Miss Penalty))
```

Here is the Table, and also `Frequency is 2.5 GHZ` and It is also provided that `20% of all instructions are of load/store type`.

[image]

By the way are there also a way to find global miss rate of UL2 in %? I'm also quite stuck on that one too.

Comment: The IL1 is an L1 instruction cache that is write-through?? That doesn't make sense, no one writes to an instruction cache.

Comment: @ErikEidt This question is given to me by my instructor. So, I don't really know how it works :/

Answer (score 0):

There are two different cache hierarchies to consider.  I cannot tell from your question post if you're trying to compute AMAT for just data operations (load & store) or for instruction access + data operations (20% of the them).

The hierarchies:

- Instruction Cache: IL1 backed by UL2 backed by Main Memory
- Data Cache: DL1 backed by UL2 backed by Main Memory

There is a stated hit time & miss rate associated with each individual cache, and, this is necessary because the caches are of different construction and size (and also in different positions in the hierarchy).

All instructions participate in accessing of the Instruction Cache, so hit/miss there applies to every instruction regardless of the nature or type of the instruction.  So, you can compute the AMAT for instruction access alone generally using the IL1->UL2->Main Memory hierarchy — be sure to use the specific hit time and miss rate for each given level in the hierarchy: 1clk & 10% for IL1; 25clk & 2% for UL2; and 120clk & 0% for Main Memory.

20% of the instructions participate in accessing of the Data Cache.

Of those that do data accesses, you can compute that component of AMAT using the DL1->UL2->Main Memory hierarchy — here you have DL1 with 2clk & 5%; UL2 with 25clk & 2%; and Main Memory with 120clk & 0%.

These numbers can be combined to an overall value that accounts for 100% of the instructions incurring the instructions cache hierarchy AMAT, and 20% of them incurring the data cache hierarchy AMAT.

As needed you can convert AMAT in cycles/clocks to AMAT in (nano) seconds.

Comment: Just to make sure, if I try to solve with that I'm getting this formula = `0.8 * ( 0.4 + 0.1 ( 10 + 0.02 * 48 ) ) + 0.2 * ( 0.8 + 0.05 ( 10 * 0.02 * 48 ) ) ` Like `% of Cache ( Hit time (IL1) + Miss Rate (IL1) * ( Hit time (UL2) + Miss Rate (UL2) * Miss Penalty )) + % of Cache ( Hit time (DL1) + Miss Rate (DL1) * ( Hit time (UL2) + Miss Rate (UL2) * Miss Penalty ))` Is this correct?